# Optimizing script for faster insert of 10,000 records in SQL Navigator?

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-navigator

I'm attempting to insert 10,000 records into a table using `INSERT` statements in SQL Navigator. The process is taking longer than expected. Does anyone have suggestions on how to expedite this operation?

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Alex', 'Alex Perera', 'Abcd 300', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');

...
...
... 10,000 records
...
...

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Bimesh', 'Bimesh Perera', '97 Elgern', 'London', '2008', 'UK');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap every thousand inserts (or so) in a PL/SQL anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ...

   ...
   ... 1,000 records
   ...
END;
/

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ...

   ...
   ... The next 1,000 records
   ...
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is each insert query will run in a separate transaction so transaction & query overhead occurs. Using any of the below ways you can over come transaction overhead.

1. Make it a multi-value insert, this will reduce query overhead and you will see some improvement.
2. Use Copy command, the idea is to put the values in a csv file and use it this is better than insert query and results in better performance.